# Creating custom Hashmap()

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

This question I am asking on the basis of my research as I was going through the source code of hashmap in decomplier , please advise Can I also create my own custom HashMap as the java HashMap is , Please advise how Can I create my own custom HashMap named MyMap..!1

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What feature is the `HashMap` missing?

Comment: For my own research and understanding..this is also a challenge to come up with own custom HashMap..!!

Comment: This question has been asked several times in the last few days, so I've flagged this as duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072127/custom-hashmap-implementation for an example which has an accepted answer.

Comment: [Knock yourself out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to write your own implementation of `HashMap`, simply implements the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface and implement its methods the way you want:

```
public class HashMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable {
    @Override
    clear() { // My implementation
    }
    // Other methods
}
```

You may also want to extend the [AbtractMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html) abstract class that provides a skeletal implementation of the `Map` interface, to minimize the effort required to implement this interface.

Answer (score 1):

you can see the source code for HashMap  in java and write of your own.

go check this link[HashMap java doc](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html)